# PHP SOAP wsdl Fatal Error & Xdebug

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, xdebug, fatal-error

I really don't understand what's happening with PHP SOAP library
I use a SOAP service, it's working well but sometimes i have the well-know 
"Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: ........"

I have read that this error was uncatchable because Xdebug was on and that the solution is to disable it to be able to catch the error,...

but i doesn't work ! the error is displayed with the orange and red colors 
do you have an idea ??

(I use the last version of wamp, i don't know how to check if i choosed 64 or 32bits but it's apache 2.2.22, php 5.3.13)

thanks in advance for your help ! :)

```
<?php
xdebug_disable();
try {
  $sc = new SoapClient("some-wrong.wsdl", array('exceptions' => true));
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error Caught :-)';
}
?>
```

I want to add that :

sometimes I have 2 warning and 1 error

```
 - Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient -> "failed to open stream ..."
 - Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient -> "failed to load external entity ..."
 - Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL -> "Couldn't load from ..."
```

and sometimes, just the fatal error

I have placed an echo just after the line new SoapClient(.....
and when there's an uncatched error, the echo is not displayed

I have to add that I call SoapClient with 
'trace'      => 1,                                                      'exceptions' => 1,

and i have this in apache error log (****** used to hide)

```
[Thu Jan 31 16:16:02 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://******?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found\n in D:\\Programmes\\wamp\\www\\******.php on line 144, referer: http://localhost/******.php
[Thu Jan 31 16:16:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  ||| faultcode: WSDL ||| faultstring: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://******?wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found\n ||| in D:\\******.php on line 201, referer: http://localhost/******.php
[Thu Jan 31 16:16:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __getLastRequestHeaders() on a non-object in D:\\Programmes\\wamp\\www\\******.php on line 204, referer: http://localhost/******.php
```

I edit my first message because i am new memebr and can t answer to my own message before 8 hours

so this morning, I have change the default stack size of apache because apache was craching with just this line in the apache error log : [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.

- I have installed visual basic 2012 (evaluation ;) )
- used the visual basic command console (start > Micrososft Visual Studio 2012 > Visual studio tools)
- checked the sire typing "cd ***my_path_containing_apache_bin_directory****\bin 
  dumpbin /all httpd.exe | find "stack"" (is was " 40000 size of stack reserve " )
- increase the size typing editbin /stack:1048576 httpd.exe
- And don't forgot to PUT ADMINISTRATOR RIGHT on the httpd.exe file + exit WANP !!! (I lost a morning because of this !, editbin was returning a LINK error !!)

-> It s strange because after to have done this, I had WSDL uncaught errors but since few hours I have not this kind of error, may be it s just the proxy list that I use that are able to connect correctly,..  ??

Comment: the error may be "well known", but it's still a good idea to quote the entire error message in the question. There may be something specific in the error message that we need to know in order to help you.

Comment: Ok i just add the error again, so the memory stack is not linked,...

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP extension does some strange things and overrides an internal PHP errorhandler. This conflicts a little with Xdebug's error overriding mechanisms. Do include the full error message though, and I can perhaps update my answer from there on.

Comment: So i just update my message with error element, is it enought or do you need other things ? if yes, could you tell me where I can find the elements you need ? thanks again :)  (you are the Derick posting on mentis for PHP bugs ?)

Comment: Hello, I just placed detailed erro message !

Comment: Derick, I have a very quick question : if I turn off Xdebug, the error will be cautched ?

Answer (score 0):

Here s the detailed error message Xdebug I get (**** to hide)

```
( ! ) Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://****?wsdl) [<a href='soapclient.soapclient'>soapclient.soapclient</a>]: failed to open stream: Une tentative de connexion a �chou� car le parti connect� n�a pas r�pondu convenablement au-del� d�une certaine dur�e ou une connexion �tablie a �chou� car l�h�te de connexion n�a pas r�pondu. in D:\Programmes\wamp\www\****.php on line 146
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  497672  {main}( )   ..\script gepir3-1.php:0
2   0.6920  695896  SoapClient->SoapClient( )   ..\script gepir3-1.php:146

( ! ) Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [<a href='soapclient.soapclient'>soapclient.soapclient</a>]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;http://****?wsdl&quot; in D:\Programmes\wamp\www\****.php on line 146
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  497672  {main}( )   ..\script gepir3-1.php:0
2   0.6920  695896  SoapClient->SoapClient( )   ..\script gepir3-1.php:146

( ! ) Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://*****.asmx?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://****asmx?wsdl" in D:\Programmes\wamp\www\****.php on line 146
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0013  497672  {main}( )   ..\script gepir3-1.php:0
2   0.6920  695896  SoapClient->SoapClient( )   ..\script gepir3-1.php:146
```

And i don't understand why my php.ini contains this parameter turned to off (the autostart is missing too

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "D:/Programmes/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:/Programmes/wamp/tmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late but Opcache module also interferes with XDebug : https://xdebug.org/docs/compat

It must be disabled in order to work with NetbeansIDE